# How do you format text in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Specifically, I am looking to zero pad a number to create a string based label.  i.e. build 7 into build 007.  You can easily add strings together, but in all my searches on formatting, padding, strings, etc...  I have not been able to find any references.

Example of what I am working with.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FileParserVersion>File Parser $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build) Build $(Revision)</FileParserVersion>
  <VersionComment>Automated build: $(FileParserVersion)</VersionComment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`This is generated: FILEPARSER_1_0_3_BUILD_7`



`What is preferred: FILEPARSER_1_0_3_BUILD_007`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following ITask:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace My.MSBuild.Tasks
{
    public class FormatRevision : Task
    {
        #region Public Properties

        [Required]
        public int Revision { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string MajorVersion { get; set; }

        [Output]
        public string OutputVersion { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region ITask Methods

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            OutputVersion = string.Format("{0}.{1}"
                , MajorVersion
                , Revision < 10 ?
                    "00" + Revision : Revision < 100 ?
                        "0" + Revision : Revision.ToString());

            Log.LogMessage("Revision: {0} -> Output Version: {1}"
                 , Revision, OutputVersion);

            return true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

MSBuild target (formatvesion.proj):

```
 <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

 <Target Name="FormatRevision"> 
    <FormatRevision MajorVersion="$(MajorVersion)" Revision="$(Revision)">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputVersion" PropertyName="FormattedVersion"/>
     </FormatRevision>
  </Target>

 <UsingTask TaskName="My.MSBuild.Tasks.FormatRevision" AssemblyFile="My.MSBuild.Tasks.dll" /> 

 </Project>
```

Invoked by command:

```
msbuild formatvesion.proj /t:FormatRevision /p:MajorVersion=1.0;Revision=7
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use CreateProperty:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FileParserVersion>File Parser $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build) Build $(Revision)</FileParserVersion>
  <VersionComment>Automated build: $(FileParserVersion)</VersionComment>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <PaddedRevision Condition="$(Revision) &lt; 1000">$(Revision)</PaddedRevision> 
  <PaddedRevision Condition="$(Revision) &lt; 100">0$(Revision)</PaddedRevision>  
  <PaddedRevision Condition="$(Revision) &lt; 10">00$(Revision)</PaddedRevision>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="test"> 

    <CreateProperty 
        Value="FILEPARSER_$(Major)_$(Minor)_$(Build)_BUILD_$(PaddedRevision)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="MyFileVersion" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <Message Text="$(VersionComment) -> $(MyFileVersion)" />

</Target>
```

Comment: I am not looking to change the version, I am trying to create a text string that will be used as a label in source control and as a folder name for deploying to QA.

Comment: CreateProperty task should do:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ckb9s9.aspx
If it doesn't, post some snippets of the project you're trying to debug.

Comment: I added a snippet in the original with the actual versus desired output.

Comment: See my updated example above. It produces the desired output given the properties in your snippet.

Comment: Perfect! Didn't even occur to me to try a bit of clever math!

Comment: /Nitpicker
Neater to do a Right("000" + Revision.ToString(), 3) ofcourse

Answer (score 12):

In 4.0+ you can do it in one line with [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) (and [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx))

```
$([System.String]::Format('FILEPARSER_$(Major)_$(Minor)_$(Build)_BUILD_{0:000}', $([MSBuild]::Add($(Revision), 0))))
```

Unfortunately the bogus "Add" is necessary to trick MSBuild to coerce $(Revision) to a number before it coerces it into the object expected by String.Format. If I don't do that it uses a string, and the padding doesn't work. The coercion inside MSBuild could be a bit smarter here.

Comment: Using $([System.Int32]::Parse($(Revision)) also works